# Kernel driver not being included

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gpio

I am writing a basic kernel driver to access some memory locations. It compiles fine, but whenever I try to insmod it, it just hangs, not sure why, here is my code

```c
  #include <linux/init.h>
  #include <linux/gpio.h>
  #include <linux/module.h>

  #define GPIO5_OE 0x4805B134

  MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
  static unsigned long *ptr;

  static int hello_init(void)
  {
#if 0
     ptr = ioremap_nocache(GPIO5_OE, 4095);
     ptr = phys_to_virt(GPIO5_OE);
     *ptr = 0xFFFFFFFF;
     if (ptr == NULL) {
         printk(KERN_ALERT "nonon");
     } else {
         printk(KERN_ALERT "yaya");
     }
     writeb(0xFFFFFFFF, ptr);
#endif
     printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
     return 0;
  }

  static void hello_exit(void)                            
  {
         printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
  }

  module_init(hello_init);
  module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Comment: Do you have some info on kernel logs/dmesg? How did you built the module? Same configuration and compiler option as the kernel you are running?

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but `ioremap_nocache` no longer exists in the latest kernels, so replace the call with `ioremap`.

Comment: Also, the `phys_to_virt` and `*ptr` are the wrong things to use for memory mapped I/O. Use `ioremap` to map the register region and `the `read[bwl]/write[bwl]` functions for register access. `4095` is a strange amount to map though.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it was my bad, the module was already included,

Comment: @IanAbbott , much thanks

Comment: @IanAbbott oh ok, yeah about the page size, its a typo , I meant it to be 4096, my bad, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Is the module working OK with the register access stuff commented out (as shown in your code), i.e. with only the `printk` calls in `hello_init` and `hello_exit`?

Comment: @IanAbbott, entire approach to get GPIO is **wrong**. One has to use `gpiod_*()` type of functions.

Comment: @0andriy Well it is also possible to do GPIO without those functions if the registers are for something with no existing GPIO controller driver.

Comment: @IanAbbott, it is also possible to shoot your self into foot... when driver suddenly appears. But I believe that the above approach comes from some kind of Arduino or whatever micro controller programming examples without understanding how it should be done in the OS. And my theory is supported by `#include <Linux/gpio.h>` which is quite outdated.

Comment: @0andriy As an example where I would not bother with a GPIO controller, sometimes some device constructed in FPGA logic might need some digital inputs or outputs, but one of the standard IP library blocks supplied by the FPGA vendor would be a GPIO block. So you would just pull that logic in. But it wouldn't be worth the effort of configuring all that GPIO stuff in the device tree for what is in effect a couple of registers for private use by some device driver.

Comment: @IanAbbott, Good theories. Obviously it is not the case here.  Simple googling: `gpio5: gpio@4805b000 { compatible = "ti,omap4-gpio"; reg = <0x4805b000 0x200>; ...`

Comment: OK so the catalog of mistakes so far is at least (1) Trying to override the existing code for the GPIO controller; (2) Using `phys_to_virt` on I/O registers; (3) Checking for `NULL` after dereferencing the pointer; (4) Using `unsigned long *` as a mmio pointer type (the width of `unsigned long` is arch-dependent as 32 or 64 bits); (5) mixing `unsigned long` (assuming 32-bit width) and 8-bit wide access (`writeb` does 8-bit wide access) to the same register (sometimes OK, depending on the hardware); (6) Maybe not having a clue what value to write to the register.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes it works with all those commented out. Tho why do you suggest linux gpio when its outdated. And why not to use direct registers?

Comment: @rhino If the GPIO controller is a standard part of the SoC, there is probably an active driver already running that is responsible for that GPIO controller. So messing with the controller's registers behind that other driver's back will leave things in an inconsistent state. Regarding outdatedness, GPIO numbers are outdated. GPIO descriptors (the gpiod and devm_gpiod stuff) is not outdated.

Comment: @IanAbbott oh ok, but there is a problem, I am using dev/mem to access gpio and some of the gpio clocks are not initialised by default, so I couldn't access them. I was compiling using yocto so I thought I could just use a driver and compile it with yocto image which will handle initialisiing clocks for me. Do you think that is a right approach?

Comment: I am not familiar with your specific system, but it sounds like a problem that ought to be corrected in the device tree.

Comment: @IanAbbott it's a beaglebone ai. Usual "hack" for this is to export the gpio from sysfs which ends up enabling the clocks. But I wanted to toggle the registers and enable it. I could do it with map.  Was trying with kernel module so that it can be built with the yocto image and run at startup and enable clocks for me.